# Finding family of continuous functions in normal topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be second countable normal (*) topological space. Prove that there is family of continuous functions $ ( f_{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}) $, $ f_{n} \colon X \rightarrow [0,1] $ so that foreach $ x \in X $ there are $m,n \in \mathbb{N} $ so that $ f_n (x) \neq f_m (x) $.

I don't have idea how to start. Any hint helps.

P.S. We consider $ X $ as normal topological space if it is $T1$ space and foreach couple of disjoint closed sets $A, B \subseteq X $ there are their two disjoint neighbourhood.

Comment: Can't you just take constant functions with distinct values?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I thought of that too, but this is task from test so I think my professor wouldn't be happy with that "basic" solution (not sure tho)

Comment: The empty space is a counter example.  If the space has only one point,then the only functions from X into R are constant.

Comment: @WilliamElliot The empty space is not a counterexample because it does not contain any $x$ ;-)

Comment: I would have expected for each $x \neq y$ some $f_n$ that has different values for those points. That’s called a point-separating family of functions. Double check the formulation. This variant is trivial and irrelevant.

Comment: @PaulFrost.  That is beside the point.  However, for each and every point x in the empty set,, a very exclusive place, x has the appropriate exceptalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not make much sense in the above form. As Alessandro Codenotti remarked in his comment, the functions $f_n(x) = 1/n$ do the job for *any* space $X$.

A more interesting question (and I guess this is meant) is this:

Find a family $f_n$ such that for any two distinct points $x,y$ there exists $n$ such that $f_n(x) \ne f_n(y)$.

Let $\mathcal B = \{B_n \}$ be a countable base for $X$. Call a pair $(n,m) \in \mathbb N^2$ *admissible* if $\overline{B}_n \cap \overline{B}_m = \emptyset$. The admissible pairs form a countable set. For each admissible $(m,n)$ choose a continuous $f_{(m,n)} : X \to I$ such that $f_{(m,n)}(x) = 0$ for $x \in \overline{B}_n$ and $f_{(m,n)}(x) = 1$ for $x \in \overline{B}_m$ (Urysohn Lemma).

This is countable family of continuos functions which can reindexed by $\mathbb N$ if you want. Let us verify that it has the desired property. So let $x,y$ be distinct points. Since $X$ is normal, there are disjoint closed neighbborhoods $N_x, N_y$ of $x,y$. Choose $n,m$ such that $x \in B_n \subset N_x$ and $y \in B_m \subset N_y$.Then $(n,m)$ is admissible and $f_{(n,m)}(x) = 0, f_{(n,m)}(y) = 1$.